# Output PHP MySQL REQUESTED DATE as XML and read it in HTML

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, xml, ajax

I've been searching for tutorials all day, but I cannot find exactly what I'm looking for.

I want to store strings in MySQL such as:
name:
Location:
Type:
Price:

What I want is to retrieve some of the date and output it into xml and read it into html.
I found a simple example here: http://demos.reynoldsftw.com/php-xml-jquery-ajax/theHTML.html and tons more like it but I cannot seem to find any that allow filtering as I don't want to get ALL of the data.

For example, a button that would set all "type" to restaurant and get only that.

Thanks!

Comment: So have you created a PHP script to connect, query and show the result from the database?

Comment: Maybe you should look up the [mysql select man page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html).

Comment: use a basic `where` clause in the sqlquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for the [`WHERE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/where-optimizations.html) clause. Basically:

```
SELECT LOCATION, TYPE, PRICE FROM STORES WHERE TYPE = 'restaurant'
```

You'd then be able to proceed exactly the same way that the tutorial does.

Comment: Thanks for the comments everyone, though what really confuses me is how to translate that request into html - as in, how to execute such a command via a button click. So what I would like to know is what this type of thing that I want is called so I can search it up on google. I tried "parsing mysql into xml via php" and "sorting database tables via php, xml" but none of those are what I'm looking for. Any suggestions where I should start? (Other than a book on mysql :P ) Thanks

Comment: Nevermind, I looked over the code and see that he used the GetData string in the button. Many thanks, but if you know any other resources that might help me I would be grateful! :)